# minOccurs/maxOccurs in XML Schema

Tags: xsd, sequence, minoccurs

Given this XML Schema snippet:

```
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="param" type="param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="format" type="format" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The intended result is valid `<data>` elements may contain 0 or more `<param>` elements followed by 0 or more `<format>` elements. Have I added the `minOccurs`/`maxOccurs` atttributes correctly, or should they be applied to the containing `<xs:sequence>`?

Correct or not, what would be the result of going one way or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done it right and you can not add min/max occurs to sequence element. Using and XML editor that supports XML Schema might help you to validate your assumptions when you are in doubt. Here is a good free ware called [XMLFox](http://www.xmlfox.com/)

Comment: Thankyou **Pangea**; Strange, the IDE (Liquid XML Studio) permits the addition of min/max on sequence nodes.

Comment: accept the answer if this is what u r looking for. if you need more info then post follow up questions

Comment: Sorry, was just waiting for the 10 minute wait time to expire and got distracted. Thanks again :)